# How to serve different web component to IE 11

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-2.x

I've configured my "polymer build" (v 2.0) to transpile an ES5 version just for IE 11, but now I need to serve only that version for IE 11 users and the ES6 version for all other browsers. What's the best way to achieve this?

Ideally, I'd like to use just one import in whichever client pages use my custom element and have some logic on the server to dish out the appropriate version, but being a newbie to web components, I don't want roll my own solution (which will probably be nasty) if there's a "right way" of doing it (so far I haven't found it, but I'll keep searching).

Thanks.

Comment: that totally depends on what your server will be using... for example polymer serve does it on the "server" level e.g. it sends the same file differently to older browser... 
but you can also build and dynamically create different html (importing form a different path)

so the question is what will be your server environment?

Comment: My server environment definitely is not "polymer serve" :-)  I believe we'll be using either Node or Apache. I was hoping there was some kind of platform neutral "best practise" for serving things to different browsers (some kind of simple logic in the element itself that then redirects to either ES5 or ES6 all done from the one import statement in HTML. Perhaps I'm dreaming too much.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a webserver, which is capable of detecting the browsers features.

The Polymer Team itself has released a library for nodeJS, which reads in your `polymer.json` file and looks in your builds directory and serves the correct build according to the features the browser of the client supports. The server itself supports H2 Push aswell, which is a nice feature.

https://github.com/Polymer/prpl-server-node

This is my builds configuration in `polymer.json`. It generates a different build for each capability. I cross checked, what versions of browsers support these technologies and added a build for each neccecary combination.

```
"builds": [{
  "name": "none",
  "browserCapabilities": [],
  "addServiceWorker": true,
  "bundle": true,
  "swPrecacheConfig": "sw-precache-config.js",
  "insertPrefetchLinks": true,
  "js": {
    "minify": true,
    "compile": true
  },
  "css": {"minify": true},
  "html": {"minify": true}
},
{
  "name": "noes6",
  "browserCapabilities": ["push", "serviceworker"],
  "addServiceWorker": true,
  "addPushManifest": true,
  "swPrecacheConfig": "sw-precache-config.js",
  "insertPrefetchLinks": true,
  "js": {
    "minify": true,
    "compile": true
  },
  "css": {"minify": true},
  "html": {"minify": true}
},
{
  "name": "nopush",
  "browserCapabilities": ["es2015", "serviceworker"],
  "addServiceWorker": true,
  "swPrecacheConfig": "sw-precache-config.js",
  "insertPrefetchLinks": true,
  "bundle": true,
  "js": {"minify": true},
  "css": {"minify": true},
  "html": {"minify": true}
},
{
  "name": "all",
  "browserCapabilities": ["es2015", "push", "serviceworker"],
  "addServiceWorker": true,
  "addPushManifest": true,
  "swPrecacheConfig": "sw-precache-config.js",
  "js": {"minify": true},
  "css": {"minify": true},
  "html": {"minify": true}
}]
```

And a simple express server, which utilizes the prpl-server library for differential serving (bare in mind, that this is ES6 Syntax):

```
const prpl = require('prpl-server');
const express = require('express');
const config = require('./build/polymer.json');

const app = express();

app.get('/*', prpl.makeHandler('./build/', config));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 80);
```